# Populating and Selecting a Drop Down List Value in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Drop down lists in ASP.NET MVC confuse me. I have a model class. The model class has a string called SelectedValue. This string represents that previously selected value. I have a collection of items I've pulled from the database. Each item of the collection has an ID and a Name value. My problem is, I don't know what the recommended way of getting this information into the UI is.

I'm not sure if I should use the ViewBag or the Model. Once the value is there though, I'm not even sure what the best way to populate the UI is. I've seen HTML helpers and people using RAZOR syntax. I'm very confused. What do people recommend?

Thank you

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("ManagerId",  (SelectList)ViewBag.Managers, string.Empty)

Comment: or using model and lambda expressions @Html.DropDownListFor(x => ManagerId, Model.Managers)

Comment: How is the correct "Manager" selected? I don't get it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how i do it, lets say you have 2 models `Team and Player`:

**Player.cs**

```
public class Player
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Team")]
    [Display(Name = "Team")]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }        

    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }        
}
```

**Team.cs**

```
 public class Team
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Full Name:")]
    public string Name { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your PlayerController:
**Note: team need to exist to create a player**

```
    private void PopulateTeamsDropDownList(object selectedTeams = null)
    {
        var teamsQuery = from d in _dataSource.Teams
                         orderby d.Name
                         select d;
        ViewBag.TeamID = new SelectList(teamsQuery, "TeamId", "Name", selectedTeams);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PopulateTeamsDropDownList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Player model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (EFootballDb db = new EFootballDb())
            {
                try
                {
                    var player = new Player
                                     {
                                         FirstName = model.FirstName,
                                         LastName = model.LastName
                                     };
                    db.Players.Add(player);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                }
            }
        }
        PopulateTeamsDropDownList(model.TeamId);
        return View(model);
    }
```

And lastly your Create View for Player would look like this:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Player</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeamId, "Pick Your Team")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("TeamId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>        

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
 }

 <div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>

 @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The way I do it is making the dropdown a part of my ViewModel .... say it is Products....  so in my ViewModel I have a

```
public SelectList Products { get; set;}
public int ProductId { get; set; }  // For the the selected Product
```

So when the View loads, and I am populating the model to return to the view in the controller, I do something like this:

```
model.Products = new SelectList(MyEnumerableofProducts, "ValueField", "TextField", {value of the selected item in the dropdown, as a string)
```

In my view, I would have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductId, Model.Products, "Please Select")



return View(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VB.Net - MVC4- Razor
This answer is almost same as Frigik( Thanks Frigik)

In your model create two fields one is the field which will hold the SelectedItem(here it is TagType of string) and the second is the drop down values (TagTypeList)

### Model Class- Tag.vb

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc

Private _tagType As String
Private _tagTypeList As List(Of SelectListItem)

Public Property TagType() As String
        Get
            Return _tagType
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _tagType = value
        End Set
End Property

Public Property TagTypeList() As List(Of SelectListItem)
        Get
            Return _tagTypeList
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of SelectListItem))
            _tagTypeList = value
        End Set
    End Property

'In the constructor

Sub New()
        TagTypeList = CommonUtility.LoadDropDownByName("TAGTYPE")
End Sub
```

### In CommonUtility class- CommonUtility.vb

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Collections.Generic


Public Shared Function LoadDropDownByName(ByVal DropDownName As String) As List(Of SelectListItem)
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim results As List(Of SelectListItem) = Nothing
        Try
            ds = objSignOn.LoadDropDown(DropDownName)   'Pass the dropdown name here and get the values from DB table which is - select ddlId, ddlDesc from <table name>
            If Not ds Is Nothing Then
                dt = ds.Tables(0)
                If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
                    results = (From p In dt Select New SelectListItem With {.Text = p.Item("ddlDesc").ToString(), .Value = p.Item("ddlId").ToString()}).ToList()
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Return results
    End Function
```

### In the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(x) x.TagType, Model.TagTypeList, "", New With {.id = "ddlTagType",.class = "dropDown", .style = "width: 140px"})
```

Here the 3rd parameter(optional) as empty which will insert the 1st item as empty in the drop down. The 1st parameter is the selectedItem which helps to populate once the value is already present in DB table.

Hope this helps who are using VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the methods above, you can also use **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288473/posting-dropdownlist-value-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc4)** approach in order to use multi Foreign Key in a Lookup table. It is very clear and effective as far as I have seen.