# Populating and Selecting Drop Down List Value from Lookup Table in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, population

I have followed the steps explained on [Populating and Selecting a Drop Down List Value in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441127/populating-and-selecting-a-drop-down-list-value-in-asp-net-mvc-4) page by Komenge Mwandila and I have been able to obtain and list data from database provided that using ONE parameter table. However, I need to use multiple dropdownlist retrieving data from just ONE LOOKUP table instead of creating another parameter table for each of them.

I want to populate multiple dropdownlist on my page retrieving data from a Lookup table in my database and my entity stracture will be simply like that:

**Student.cs**

...

Student ID

Student Department (ddl 1)

Student Language (ddl 2)

...

**Lookup.cs**

...

Lookup ID

Lookup Type (i.e. Department, Language)

Lookup Value

...

So, assume that I have Student table and a LOOKUP table containing Department and Language records in it and when populating Department data I will use "Department" and when populating Language data I will use "Language" as **Lookup Type**.  What I would like to do at here to use just a single table for the few parameters instead of using another table for each of them). Could you clarify me please how to do this by modifying the example [Populating and Selecting a Drop Down List Value in ASP.NET MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441127/populating-and-selecting-a-drop-down-list-value-in-asp-net-mvc-4) page by Komenge Mwandila? 
Thanks in advance to Komenge Mwandila and those who help me. 
BR